# Abort a "showDialog" in the initializer of that dialog

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I've got a main window with a button that calls another dialog like this:

```
TableView dialog = new TableView();
dialog.ShowDialog();
```

In that view's xaml.cs constructor it looks something like this:

```
public TableView()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.tableViewModel = this.DataContext as TableViewModel;
    this.tableViewModel.CloseAction += this.Close;
}
```

This, of course, calls the constructor of the view model *where I am sometimes encountering an exception*. I have handled this exception in the view model's constructor (`try{}catch{}`), but currently the TabeView still shows (just looks wonky without the proper stuff in it). To solve this, I was putting in the xaml.cs constructor:

```
public TableView()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.tableViewModel = this.DataContext as TableViewModel;
    this.tableViewModel.CloseAction += this.Close;

    if (this.tableViewModel.ListOfViewModels == null)
        this.Close();
}
```

but then the `dialog.ShowDialog();` returns an error (trying to show a dialog that has already been closed). Is there a good practice way for me to do this? Maybe a way to call the `this.Close();` that doesn't throw an exception in the `dialog.ShowDialog();`?

Comment: Isn't it possible to fix the exception instead of trying to work around it?

Comment: @SledgeHammer No the exception comes from trying to read a .csv that the user could have open in Excel or something. So if that's the case, I'm trying to show a message box, then abort the loading of this TableView

Comment: Did you try put the try catch around the new / ShowDialog call in the main form instead? That way the dialog won't construct properly and won't show and you can display the error box from the main form. Another option is to restructure your code so the dialog is shown in an "uninitialized" state with the error box on top of it, but then the user would have to close 2 dialogs.

Comment: Stop doing work in the constructor.  Remove everything except `InitializeComponent();`  Perform this work where you construct the dialog.   That way, you'll know its broke and you'll never call ShowDialog().

Answer (score 0):

The question is arguably too broad. You've left out a lot of details, which opens the door to a number of possible solutions. That said, I think there are some basic ways to approach this:

1. Don't catch the exception in the view model constructor. Let it propagate out to the code that creates the `TableView` object, and have that code not call `ShowDialog()` if an exception occurs.
2. Catch the exception in the view model and provide a suitable "failed to initialize" state for the view to present. Then go ahead and call `ShowDialog()` and let the dialog be shown to the user. Optionally, allow the dialog to close after it's been opened after e.g. five seconds (with a suitable warning to the user than the dialog will be closing). Of course, adding this optional behavior will require more coordination between the view and view model; you'll want for the view to check the view model state, then start a timer after which the dialog will be closed.
3. Perform the exception-throwing initialization *prior* to creating the dialog object. Then if it succeeds, pass it to the dialog constructor which in turn can pass it to the view model constructor. Alternatively, allow the initialized data to be set after construction via a property.

The above is far from a comprehensive list, but represents what are likely the most desirable solutions given the state of the code now. If you want something more specific, please provide a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows clearly what your scenario looks like.